# web3Provider in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web3-react

I try to use Web3-react v6 in Next JS and a got an error when try to wrapper mi entery app with the provider,

In `_app.jsx` I have this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Web3ReactProvider } from '@web3-react/core/dist';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';
import './styles.css';
import { getLibrary } from '../config/web3';

//import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css"; include library if you need

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Web3ReactProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

But then I got

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bjvalmaseda/Dev/Dochain/frontend/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:1:190)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.web3/dist/web3.min (/home/bjvalmaseda/Dev/Dochain/frontend/.next/server/pages/_app.js:669:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/bjvalmaseda/Dev/Dochain/frontend/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` is not defined on the server side.
Since you are using NextJS I'm assuming you're doing SSR and that is where the error is raised.

To avoid this error you can:

1. Not use `window` (if possible)
2. Use useEffect hook

Sample:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (window){
    window.addEventListener('keyup', setCorrectElement);
  }
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', setCorrectElement);
  }
}, [])
```

3. Check if `window` exists in the current context

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") /* you are on the server */
```

If this error is thrown from an external library chances are it does not support SSR.